# How do I, with the help of jQuery, find similar classes between multiple elements, and count these?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to sort and count images by class.

[www.paintings.directory](http://www.paintings.directory)

Example: Three images have the class 'France' so a '(3)' appears behind 'France' in the menu.

(when I then click on France in the menu, all images without class 'France' hide. no trouble here. I got this sorted.)

In the working example below there is simply too much handwork and typing needed and I'm having trouble figuring out how to automate the process. later on I am looking at 100 countries, 300+ years, etc...

```
var colorBlue = $('img.blue').length;
var colorGold = $('img.gold').length;
var colorPink = $('img.pink').length;

var countryFrance = $('img.france').length;
var countryGreece = $('img.greece').length;
var countrySweden = $('img.sweden').length;

var date1980 = $('img.1980').length;
var date1985 = $('img.1985').length;
var date1990 = $('img.1990').length;

$('#colorBlueCount').text('(' + colorPink + ')');
$('#colorGoldCount').text('(' + colorGold + ')');
$('#colorPinkCount').text('(' + colorPink + ')');

$('#countryFranceCount').text('(' + countryFrance + ')');
$('#countryGreeceCount').text('(' + countryGreece + ')');
$('#countrySwedenCount').text('(' + countrySweden + ')');

$('#date1980Count').text('(' + date1980 + ')');
$('#date1985Count').text('(' + date1985 + ')');
$('#date1990Count').text('(' + date1990 + ')');
```

I'm hoping to somehow, with the help of jQuery, figure out, which IMG classes and UL menu items are exactly similar, so they will be counted automatically.

Something like this (bit embarrassing):

If 'img.class' == 'ul.class' add 'img.length' to 'span' of 'ul.class'.

Hope this didn't make you spit out milk through your nose.

Where do I start, what do I read, I have searched for similar problems, and try to read about sorting and comparing the class of two elements, but I feel that now I am stuck....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* sort by class */

  $('ul').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this).attr('class');
    $('img').show();
    $('img').not('.' + filter).hide();
  });
  
  /* image zoom */

    $('img').click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
            $(this).removeClass("open");
        }
        else {
            $('img').removeClass("open");
            $(this).addClass("open");
        }
    });
  
  /* count classes */

  function countClass() {

    var colorBlue = $('img.blue').length;
    var colorGold = $('img.gold').length;
    var colorPink = $('img.pink').length;

    var countryFrance = $('img.france').length;
    var countryGreece = $('img.greece').length;
    var countrySweden = $('img.sweden').length;

    var date1980 = $('img.1980').length;
    var date1985 = $('img.1985').length;
    var date1990 = $('img.1990').length;

    $('#colorBlueCount').text('(' + colorPink + ')');
    $('#colorGoldCount').text('(' + colorGold + ')');
    $('#colorPinkCount').text('(' + colorPink + ')');

    $('#countryFranceCount').text('(' + countryFrance + ')');
    $('#countryGreeceCount').text('(' + countryGreece + ')');
    $('#countrySwedenCount').text('(' + countrySweden + ')');

    $('#date1980Count').text('(' + date1980 + ')');
    $('#date1985Count').text('(' + date1985 + ')');
    $('#date1990Count').text('(' + date1990 + ')');
  }
  countClass();

});
```

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  top: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* S E C T I O N */

section {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section h1 {
  color: forestgreen;
}

section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

section ul:hover {
  color: royalblue;
}

section ul span {
  color: gainsboro;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(40vh + 40px);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

img.open {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 70vh;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 100vh 100vw;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by country</h1>
    <ul class="sweden">Sweden <span id="countrySwedenCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="greece">Greece <span id="countryGreeceCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="france">France <span id="countryFranceCount"></span></ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by color</h1>
    <ul class="blue">Blue <span id="colorBlueCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="gold">Gold <span id="colorGoldCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="pink">Pink <span id="colorPinkCount"></span></ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by date</h1>
    <ul class="1980">1980 <span id="date1980Count"></span></ul>
    <ul class="1985">1985 <span id="date1965Count"></span></ul>
    <ul class="1990">1990 <span id="date1990Count"></span></ul>
  </section>

</nav>

<main>

  <img class="sweden gold 1985" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden blue 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="greece gold 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="france pink 1980" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden gold 1985" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden blue 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="greece gold 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="france pink 1980" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">

</main>
```

The website has the following options to click on:

My jQuery

Comment: Has nothing tod o with your question but why don't you start with semantic HTML first?

Comment: Aren't 'main' and 'section' semantic HTML elements, I'm not sure what you mean, would you mind explaining further? Thanks

Comment: You are right, this is semantic correct. But if you have something to select, use a form field (like a select?) if you have to use a list, use a list with correct HTML syntax (you are missing `<li>` elements). Also you don't have three lists, you have one list with three selections, that's also wrong. If you have a list of images, maybe use a list for this instead of just adding the images.

Comment: Thank you this makes a lot of sense. There are holes in my coding, which I now realise have nothing to do with a neater, cleaner or more dynamic HTML, it's cheating in a way and I should not code so 'minimal'. Thank you for pointing this out. Every day is a school day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$("section ul").each(function() {
  var $class = $(this).attr("class");
  if ($(this).find("span").length) {
    $(this).find("span").text("(" + $('main img.' + $class).length + ")")
  } else {
    $(this).append("<span> (" + $('main img.' + $class).length + ")</span>")
  }
})
```

This will make your code more dynamic.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* sort by class */

  $('ul').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var filter = $(this).attr('class');
    $('img').show();
    $('img').not('.' + filter).hide();
  });

  /* image zoom */

  $('img').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      $(this).removeClass("open");
    } else {
      $('img').removeClass("open");
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }
  });

  $("section ul").each(function() {
    var $class = $(this).attr("class");
    if ($(this).find("span").length) {
      $(this).find("span").text("(" + $('main img.' + $class).length + ")")
    } else {
      $(this).append("<span> (" + $('main img.' + $class).length + ")</span>")
    }
  })

});
```

```css
nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40vh;
  top: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


/* S E C T I O N */

section {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section h1 {
  color: forestgreen;
}

section ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}

section ul:hover {
  color: royalblue;
}

section ul span {
  color: gainsboro;
}

main {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(40vh + 40px);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: zoom-in;
}

img.open {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 70vh;
  width: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 100vh 100vw;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by country</h1>
    <ul class="sweden">Sweden <span id="countrySwedenCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="greece">Greece <span id="countryGreeceCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="france">France <span id="countryFranceCount"></span></ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by color</h1>
    <ul class="blue">Blue <span id="colorBlueCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="gold">Gold <span id="colorGoldCount"></span></ul>
    <ul class="pink">Pink <span id="colorPinkCount"></span></ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h1>Sort by date</h1>
    <ul class="1980">1980</ul>
    <ul class="1985">1985 <span id="date1965Count"></span></ul>
    <ul class="1990">1990 <span id="date1990Count"></span></ul>
  </section>

</nav>

<main>

  <img class="sweden gold 1985" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden blue 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="greece gold 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="france pink 1980" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden gold 1985" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="sweden blue 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="greece gold 1990" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">
  <img class="france pink 1980" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg/158px-Mona_Lisa.jpg">

</main>
```

Comment: Does this mean I will need manually add a `<span></span>` after every `ul` or is there a way to have jQuery render the span too?

Answer (score 0):

So far, from what i understood u want to count all elements with similar class in jquery?
if so, you can simply use the following code in the example:

```
var swedencount = $('.sweden');
console.log(swedencount.length);
```

the "swedencount" will count all elements with class "sweden". if you wanna know if the element is a specific type (example an Image) you can use the following full example:

```
var swedencount = $('.sweden');
for(i=0;i<swedencount.length;i++){
  if (swedencount[i].nodeName == 'IMG') {
    console.log ('That element is an image')
  }
}
```

this example will count all element with same class name, and output "that element is an image" if its a type of "img".

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thank you, what I was trying to is eliminate 'swedenCount' and 'franceCount' etc, as I will end up with over a hundred different entities later on.